# Yii2 how to access POST data that's been sent using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I want to create a variable within my controller function that equals the POST value however I am unsure on how to access the POST value.

An answer would be great but any tips for debugging would be great too.

I have tried $_POST['save_id'] as well as $_POST[0]['save_id']

```
$('#save-file').click(function() {

    var fileid = $(this).data('fileid');

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/files/save",
            data: { 'save_id' : fileid },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               //do something
                console.log(fileid);
               alert("working");
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {

                //do something else
                alert("not working");

            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html#request-parameters

Comment: Whiich php files do you want call with your ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for your url if the code is inside a PHP file i suggest you a proper path eg :

```
   url: <?=Url::to(['/files/save']) ?>,
```

(Remenber of add `use use yii\helpers\Url;`)

If not a php refer to the absolute path properly

inside your FilesController in save Action

```
public function actionSave()
{
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        //data: { 'save_id' : fileid },
        $mySaveId =  $data['save_id']
        // your logic;
        ......
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196185/unable-to-post-the-data-from-view-to-controller-in-yii2) related to it ?